# Chrome's webpage's display

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I am using chrome to look up some webpages, but some of these webpages' color are not normal, they are grey. For example,this is the wall street journal

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTlkh.png]

Generally speaking,the main color of this webpage is white, but the color is grey.What is the problem?

My reputation is not reaching 10,maybe my image could not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all Chrome extensions, if that fixes the problem re-enable them one by one until you discover the extension causing the problem. This is common with ad-blocker extensions or extensions that alter the display of the page. Blocking known ad sites in your hosts file can do the same.

Comment: Oh,that is not useful. I disabled all the extensions of my chrome, but the color is still grey. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Perhaps the Chrome Inspect window will give you some idea of what is happening? You can look through the page code and stylesheets to determine where the color is being set and perhaps what may be interfering with it.